# How do I covert Photoshop swatches to illustrator swatches in CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cs5, swatches

I want to bring my Photoshop swatch library into Illustrator.

I've tried saving `swatches for exchange` and then opening them in a `New Swatch Library` in Illustrator, but the colors become corrupted.

Comment: What does "Colors become corrupted" mean?